# Can not construct a array_view object

Tags: c++

My problem is that this code can be built, but i can not run this, the program stops and on my screen pops up an error and I don't understand why. I tried to debug the program and I found out that any array_view object can not be built

```
#include <amp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace concurrency;

void perform_calculation(std::vector<int>& vA, std::vector<int>&vB,
std::vector<int>vC, int M, int N)
{
    extent<2> e(M, N);
    array_view<int,2> a(e, vA); // the program stops here
    array_view<int,2> b(e, vB);
    array_view<int,2> c(e, vC);
    c.discard_data();
    index<2> idx(0, 0);

    parallel_for_each(e,
        [=](index<2> idx)restrict(amp)
    {
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
    });
    c.synchronize();
}

void do_it()
{
    const int M = 1024;
    const int N = 1024;

    std::vector<int> vA(M * N);
    std::vector<int> vB(M * N);

    int i = 0;
    std::generate(vA.begin(), vA.end(), [&] {return i++; });
    std::generate(vB.begin(), vB.end(), [&] {return i--; });

    std::vector<int> vC(M * N);

    perform_calculation(vA, vB, vC, M, N);
}

int main()
{
    do_it();

    std::cout << "Hit any key to exit..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

[The error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4fV1.png)

> Exception thrown at 0x0F7BC933 (vcamp140d.dll) in AMP01.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.

Maybe I didn't read something from the tutorial, I know I messed something up but I can't figure out what... Sorry for being a beginner and for my bad english.

Comment: Are you sure this happens with the code above? I ran it in VS2015 (Debug/Win32) without any errors.

Comment: I compile and run it fine on VS2015 Community Edition. What compiler are you using?

Comment: `C++-CLI` is for Microsoft's .Net extensions to C++ and I don't see any code here that indicates you are using that.

Comment: @SimonKraemer, yes it's the exact code from my compiler.

Comment: @vordhosbn, the same compiler.

Comment: @crashmstr, I didn't notice that. I think i added that by mistake.

Comment: What happens if you hit continue, when you see this error? And if you build in release and try to run from outside Visual Studio, does it work?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado, if I hit continue, i get the error again and again and again... If I try to run from outside Visual Studio i get a messagebox that says D3DCOMPILER_47.dll is missing from my computer. I added that and the program just stops

Comment: I solved that. The only thing that i needed to do is to set Solution Configurations to "Release." Thank you so much for helping me!